# How do I install numpy and matploblib on RedHat?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, matplotlib

I have downloaded `numpy` and `matploblib` tar.gz files. Now I want to install them on RedHat 5.

I don't have root privileges. I have read INSTALL documents but I didn't understand how to install these.

1. Can I install these libraries without root privileges?
2. If yes, how do I install them? Could you give me exact commands?
3. Don't these libraries consist of python modules? So all I have to do is copy those modules to PYTHONPATH, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, just use the `--user` flag when installing the package (provided you have a recent enough version of Python)

   More info on the `--user` flag is available in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html). Usually, a `~/.local` directory will be created (if necessary), your packages should be present in `~/.local/lib/python$VERSION/site-packages`.
2. Install NumPy *before* matplotlib. To do that, just enter

   ```
   python setup.py install --user
   ```

   in the directory where you unzipped the archive. Repeat for matplotlib.

   Don't forget to read the [installation](http://www.scipy.org/Installing_SciPy/Linux) instructions for NumPy (and for [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) too, of course). Should you have a problem, it'll likely be covered in the documentation.
3. Once you're done with the installation, just update your `$PYTHONPATH` with a link to `~/.local/lib/python$VERSION/site-packages`

---

If you have an old version of Python that doesn't recognize the `--user` flag, you should still be able to give the path of the installation with the `--prefix` flag.  You could use `--prefix=~/.local` in order to match what would have happened if you had a more recent version of Python
(Note that this topic is covered in the NumPy installation guide...).

Comment: What is "--user"? If I install it that way, can all users use and run these libraries and applications? That's what I want. Should I write "--user" my username?

Comment: @alwbtc: Strange. What command did you enter, exactly? What's your python version? Numpy, matplotlib?

Comment: "Python 2.4.3", "numpy-1.6.2", "matplotlib-1.1.1"

Comment: I entered: "python setup.py install --user"

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you answer my last question, If I install it as "python setup.py install --prefix=~/.local", can other uses run scripts which uses numpy and matplotlib?

Comment: As long as you update your PYTHONPATH as mentioned in point #3, you should be OK.